# How are multiple record custom fields handled in Drupal webforms?

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, multi-record

Can't find anything on this from my searches, so thought I'd put the question here: If I use fields from a multiple-record custom field set in a Drupal webform via the webform_civicrm integration module (let's say I want to record a list of qualifications, for example), then I can expose up to 9 instances of those fields in the webform.

If the same user comes back some time later, as a logged in user, and fills a new instance of the webform, will these fields be pre-filled with any existing data held for the user, or will blank fields be presented to enable them to add further records?

I can see sensible use cases for both options, but in my current use case I want to ensure that the user is provided with a clean form to enable them to add new records rather than edit/overwrite existing records. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Starting to experiment with this right now Graham.

Comment: From what I understand if existing data will be edited/updated unless there are sufficient instances of the fields in the webforms to provide for an empty set of fields, in which case a new record can be created. Logical, but not ideal, and in some cases I can see that this would be unworkable.

Comment: We ran into that as well.  In one of our cases, I was trying to use it for medications and would hit the webform limit of 9 or 10 (can't remember off the top of my head).  I am currently getting away from using multiple record custom field sets because of the inability to target specific records.

Comment: Any progress on this? I ran into the problem that webform could happily create a new occurrence of the custom record if none existed before, but I couldn't find how to make it create a new record when there is an existing record - which is what I wanted.  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I worked around this for the reason given by Paul Mosey. Might be worth posting an issue on the webform_civicrm module page, or adding to this one: https://www.drupal.org/node/2242287, but it looks like Coleman is not about to jump on it.