# How to target record id for multiple record custom field set in Webfom?

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, drupal-views

Drupal 7.40
Webform-Civi Integration 7.x-4.13

Similar to Graham's question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/how-are-multiple-record-custom-fields-handled-in-drupal-webforms).

Use case:
Setting up goal plans that look like this:

Long-Term Goal 1
  Short-Term Goal A
  Short-Term Goal B
  Short-Term Goal C

Long-Term Goal 2
  Short-Term Goal A
  Short-Term Goal B
  Short-Term Goal C

Long-Term Goal 3
  Short-Term Goal A
  Short-Term Goal B
  Short-Term Goal C

etc.

I've created a custom field set that allows multiple records.
Each record contains:

Long-Term Goal
Short-Term Goal A
Short-Term Goal B
Short-Term Goal C

We have a View that lists the goal plans with a link to edit the goal plan profile.  However, it is large and confusing for the end user.

I'd like to create a Webform that targets each individual record not all of them.

Custom fields have ids in their tables, but I can't see a way to implement them in Views or Webform.

I believe I could expose it to Views but even if I can, is there any way for Webform to use the record id?

Comment: Will flesh out this option if you want, but for a very similar use case we opted to use Activities rather than contact based custom fields

Comment: Activities and Cases seem the way to go in our case too Pete.  We are in the process of converting most multiple record custom field sets to either Activities or Cases.

Comment: When you say "I'd like to create a Webform that targets each individual record not all of them" please can you explain what you mean? In webform's configuration you can enable the fields/activities' fields that you want to be updated.

Comment: This is only related to multiple record custom field sets.  I set up a few, but in hindsight they appear to be very limiting.  Getting creative with Activities and/or Cases seems the easier way to go in the long run for things that you want multiple records of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to target a single record of a multiple record custom field set with a Webform.  As stated above, using Activities and Cases for this type of data as opposed to multiple record custom field sets is the better option for our use case.