# Creating custom fields: 1) previous address 2) number of years at this address

Tags: custom-fields

I would like to create a set of custom fields, whereby the user is asked to enter data relating to the location of the contact's previous address, and another field specifying the amount of time the contact was at that address.

The user should be able to continue adding locations, until there is data going back x years.

Is this possible to implement from within Civi?

Answer (score 1):

You can create 'multiple record' fields which will allow your users to keep adding more sets of the same fields until you have enough to cover your 'x years'.

There is documentation in the book [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/)

Hope that is what you are needing.

NOTE: Multiple Rows do come with limitations and gotchas

Comment: Thank you Pete.  I created a new set for the questions which require multiple answer functionality.  Is there a way to carry this over into a Drupal webform?

Comment: based on answers on these other tickets, sounds possible: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/how-are-multiple-record-custom-fields-handled-in-drupal-webforms or http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-to-target-record-id-for-multiple-record-custom-field-set-in-webfom

Comment: A word of caution about using multiple row fields: they can't be exported. I've gotten around this on Drupal with the Views and Views Export modules.

Comment: Yes good reminder for everyone Dan, Multiple Rows do come with limitations and gotchas.